# Import multiple csv files into pandas in my function and importing

Tags: pandas, dataframe, function, module, python-import

I would like create my function in import_data.py and load some csv files from folder. The function was no invoked in my second file. However, I was not able to figure it out. I can't write functions correctly. Here's what I have so far:

File import_data.py:

```
import pandas as pd
    """Load csv files to DataFrame"""

def data_load():
    train_data = pd.read_csv("data/train_data.csv", header=None)
    test_data = pd.read_csv("data/test_data.csv", header=None)
    train_labels = pd.read_csv("data/train_labels.csv", header=None)

train_data, test_data, train_labels = data_load()
data = [train_data, test_data, train_labels]
names = ["train_data", "test_data", "train_labels"]

return [train_data, test_data, train_labels]
```

Second file:

```
from import_data import *
print(train_data.shape)
```

> NameError: name 'train_data' is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return statement should be part of the function otherwise the function won't return anything:

import_data.py:

```
import pandas as pd
    """Load csv files to DataFrame"""

def data_load():
    train_data = pd.read_csv("data/train_data.csv", header=None)
    test_data = pd.read_csv("data/test_data.csv", header=None)
    train_labels = pd.read_csv("data/train_labels.csv", header=None)

    return [train_data, test_data, train_labels]
```

Now this file won't magically run. You'll have to call the function `data_load` in order to execute it. So in your main python file (the one you're going to execute) you should include:

```
from import_data import *

train_data, test_data, train_labels = data_load()
print(train_data.shape)
```

Now `train_data` is defined in your main python file and it won't throw the `NameError` upon `print(train_data.shape)`.